# How can I loop over form data using serialized (jQuery / Ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get post id and insert it into database after user click on add to favorite button.

The problem that all the post are return id 30  which is the last id in the database.

My php/html code

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_posts)) {
    <i style="float:right;" class="fa fa-pinterest-square">
       <form id="pin_post" method="post"> ';
          if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
               <input type="hidden" value="'. $_SESSION['user_id'].'" name="user_id" /> 
            }

            <input type="hidden" value="'.$row['post_id'].'" name="post_id[]" />

        </form>
     </i>
```

The jQuery / Ajax code

```
<script>

    $(document).on("click",".fa-pinterest-square",function(e) {


        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#pin_post').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

I'm getting last id in the database when I click any post.

Please help me to get the id of each post when I click on the

Comment: so should I put the form out  the loop  or what?

Comment: you should be getting parse errors here. `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_posts)) {
    <i style="float:right;" class="fa fa-pinterest-square">...</i>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `#pin_post` when serializing it you will get the last hit when jQuery is looking for `#pin_post`. Either you should use a unique id or something like this

```
$(document).on("click",".fa-pinterest-square",function(e) {
    var form = $(this).find('form'); //Since the form is child to <i>
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked like a charm.   Can you explain how   var form = $(this).find('form');  get the id for each post coming from the data base.

Comment: That is because when you are trying to access `#pin_post` you have to be sure of that the `<element id="pin_post">` is unique (not existing elsewhere in the HTML), the id attribute always has to be unique! What I did was based on the the click event, accessed its children, in this case the <form> that you want to serialize. (Do mark the comment as correct)

Comment: Thank you very much.  Sure I will do that.